# React, about not mutating state

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a state

```
state = {
  inner1: {
     inner2: {
        foo: var1
     }
  }
}
```

I want to update `foo` to `var2`.

Should I create a copy of `state` `inner1` `inner2` so that shallowEqual would see `state` `inner1` `inner2` changed?

in code, it would be something like

```
newState = _.merge({}, state, {
   inner1: {
     innner2: {
        foo: var2
     }
   }
})
```

(Although I'm not entirely sure how _.merge works, it seems sometimes counter intuitive)

So, conceptually, I'm creating a shallow copy until (nested level) I find the object I want to change.

Or would it be more appropriate to update `inner2` only?

```
var { inner2 } = state.inner1

var newInner2 = _.merge({}, inner2, {
    foo: var2
})

state.inner2 = newInner2
```

Comment: It depends on what you do it for. reactjs does not care, it would start rendering loop as soon as `setState` is invoked.

Comment: I guess I have to add "I want to take advantage of shallowEqual"

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Lodash, you could just use the spread operator.
This example assumes that there are more properties on `inner1` and `inner2` than those illustrated in your question. If not, the spreads are entirely obsolete.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  inner1: {
    ...prevState.inner1,
    inner2: {
       ...prevState.inner2,
       foo: var2,
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: "React only looks for changes to object references" --- react itself does not make any checks at all

Comment: You are correct. React actually performs a diff on the DOM and virtual DOM. I'll remove the last line of my answer.